# In/Out variables in C

Tags: c

Imagine you have a function in C that initialize a pointer:

`void initialize(Pointer * p);`

I would say the parameter p is an [out] parameter.

Then we have a function which gets the p and manipulate it.

`void manipulate(Pointer * p)`

Now I have doubt if p is [out] or [in/out].

I would say [out] because we just manipulate it.
I would say [in/out] because what comes in already has been initialized.

I was wondering which one is true?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the declaration which indicates that.  The only true determination is what the code within the function does.

In more modern implementations, the `const` keyword can be used to indicate read only parameters:

```
void manipulate(const Pointer * p)
```

This indicates that `*p` cannot be assigned within the function, so it is read only (or `in`) type.  However, if `const` is missing, it could still be read only.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is entirely true.

You are passing a pointer to function. So it can be considered as *in* since you pass the pointer's *value*. Also, it can be considered as *out* since you are presumably changing its pointee.

So I won't buy this *in* or *out* theory. I'll leave it as just a pointer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct in/out concept in standard C. However you can do it by defining you own macro.

Actually all parameters passing is done by only 2 methods.

```
1. pass by value
2. pass by address
```

And it's up to you how you manipulate.
If you don't want to modify incoming paramneter then use `const`.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Pointer` type is not itself an actual pointer, like `typedef int *Pointer`, then the `initialize` function can not allocate memory for the argument.

In that case you have to pass the *pointer* as reference, i.e. you have to pass the address of the pointer, which means the function should take a pointer to a pointer as argument:

```
void initialize(Pointer **p)
{
    *p = malloc(sizeof(Pointer));
    ...
}
```

Call as

```
Pointer *p;
initialize(&p);
```

Answer (score 0):

**example 1**

```
char buf[256];

void manipulate(char * p)
{
    strcpy(p,"Just test string");
}

int main()
{
    manipulate(buf);
    printf("%s\n",buf);
}
```

In the above example the buf string is initialized as staic buffer memory. The  `manipulate` function here will copy a message to the buffer memory.

**example 2**

```
char *buf;

void initialize(char **p)
{
    *p = malloc(256*sizeof(char));
}

void manipulate(char * p)
{
    strcpy(p,"Just test string");
}

int main()
{
    initialize(&buf)
    manipulate(buf);
    printf("%s\n",buf);
}
```

In the second example the buf is a pointer to a string which is not initialized in the definition. the initialize function here wwill `initialize` the buffer that's why we used `char **p`  this means that the function will initialize the address of the pointer. if we pas the variable with `*p` as  done in the function `manipulate()` this means that we can only change the content of the memory which the pointer `p` is pointing on.